# Sending large number of emails from your server

Tags: php, email

Background: I run a site which is basically free. It has a sizeable number of email subscribers but because currently there's no pricing model I cannot afford to use Mailchimp to overcome their 2K subscriber limit.

I'm thinking to send it out myself. If I've got an array of ~12000 emails and I use PHP to send out the newsletter, from the server what will the impact be on the server? Could response time for the actual site users (seeing as the website is hosted on the same server) be impacted? Could the server crash? How long might this task take approximately?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? if so, this is going to be an issue.

Comment: we send a thousand emails a minute per core. but since there are a million variables, no one could possibly know your throughput.

Comment: I'm on GoDaddy's Economy Web Hosting Linux. Why will this be an issue?

Comment: @Dagon what are some details I could provide to narrow it down?

Comment: well you have chosen the worst host ever. and their limit is 250 emails a day, so i wouldent even bother (12000/250= 48 days)

Comment: @Dagon one alternative I had in mind is to spawn up a whole new VM on Heroku for free and just use that for email campaigns. I'm not sure if this will work but maybe this is a whole new question in itself.

Answer (score 1):

in my experience, [PHP list](http://www.phplist.com/) would be your best option for this as it's the most popular open source email managment system. Depending on your host, they may have limits on the number of outgoing emails that you send so it's best to check with them first and then configure it so that it is inline with their rules. It takes some configuring, but once you're up and running, it's very easy to use.

In saying that - after managing much more sizeable lists for a good 5-6 years, I've now migrated them all over to [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com).

All in all, PHP List will definitely do what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Is PHP List able to do send out 12K emails for free? I literally am able pay next to nothing to send out the emails, hence I'm thinking of implementing it myself

Comment: Yes, it's free. It does however add some text to the footer e.g "powered by php list". Given your Host has a 250 email per day limit, then you would most probably look at switching to a host that has a higher outgoing limit and then install PHP List once you've switched.

Comment: Yeah I did not realize the 250 email limit. This will not work - I'll be taking a look at PHP List to see whether this will be a useful alternative

Comment: he means you have to install it on your host, so the limit will still get you